# Echo -e escape sequences?

Tags: linux, echo

After days of researching I still don't understand why :

```
echo -e a\nb
```

gives me an output of :  anb

While

```
echo -e 'a\nb'   -----> Gives me an output of 

 a
 b
```

I understand that echo -e  activates the escape sequence , So it should work on the first example but it doesn't .. I'm lost.
I tried same commands in Ubuntu and OpenSuse .. both , same results .
Any Help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell interprets the `\` character when the `\` character is not quoted, and the shell (normally) interprets it differently than the echo command.

```
echo -e a\nb
```

In the above, the shell interprets `\n` as `n`, because the characters are not in quotes. So the shell passes the characters `anb` to the echo command.

```
echo -e 'a\nb'
```

In the above, the shell passes the exact characters `a\nb` to the echo command, because the single quotes tell the shell not to interpret the `\`.

Note that bash supports a form of quoting that interprets ANSI C escapes directly:

```
echo $'a\nb'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . it really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

In `echo 'a\nb'`
This means `\n` , `\r`, `\r\n`  is the new line or enter key  in your keyboard. It parses those string. so that the result is:

```
a
b
```

In `echo a\nb`, It doesnt parse but just print it as normal string.
To enable or disable backslash interpretation, you can `-e` to `-E`.

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

ref: http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo